# 3D ring/rope wooden puzzle solution?

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, topology

I have a Eureka 3d ["Puzzle G"](https://www.joyhobby.co.kr/mall/Item.asp?siteid=joyhobby&itemid=538853&catid=7751):*

[image]

The box lists 3 puzzles:

1. Remove the ring
2. Remove the rope
3. Move the ring to the other side

While I was able to [solve](http://collection.cassetete.free.fr/2_corde/model_g/model_g.htm) shows the first puzzle, I haven't managed puzzles 2 or 3 (and can't find any info online).

Is anyone familiar with this style of puzzle and can offer a solution to either of the 2nd and 3rd puzzles?

---

* Also known as "Model G", "Gringo", "Stumps Advanced Puzzle Model P" etc.

**Notes:**

- [Discussion of puzzle](http://www.zwavel.com/%7Ezwavelaars/index.php?itemid=665)
- Note Eureka also produces the [similar puzzle](https://japaneseringpuzzle.com/) featured in a famous [Knight Scoop episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLVJlbNxXeo) ("Puzzle O"). Solution published [here](https://www.eureka-puzzle.eu/eureka/index.php/en/solutions/eureka-puzzles-solutions/31-string-puzzles/139-eureka-solution-puzzle-o.html).

Comment: semi related: this was very entertaining https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDw5Y8qSmBk

Comment: @qwr This is the reason I bought it! I saw it in a shop and it reminded me of that episode, but the two puzzles are *slightly* different, so I couldn't use the video to solve it haha